# How to style text in HTML?

Tags: html, css

I have this code,

```
<td bgcolor="#ffffff">
   <div align="center"><strong>Please select country: </strong></div> 
</td>
```

How can I add font size to this code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: really bad question you should read CSS

Comment: googling is not a crime!

Comment: Can i suggest looking up some tutorials to give you a better understanding of how to use html and CSS. http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_intro.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `font-size` like

```
<td bgcolor="#ffffff">
   <div align="center" style="font-size:14px;"><strong>Please select country: </strong></div>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a class to your div.Then define the style in css for that class.Since inline styling is not encouraged.

```
<td bgcolor="#ffffff">
     <div class="my_div" align="center">
          <strong>Please select country: </strong>
     </div>
</td>
```

In css

```
.my_div{
font-size: 10px;
}
```